# PM2 alternative that supports proxy?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I know this a general question but I cant find a proper solution online. I am facing issues with deploying my node application at our work using PM2, unfortunately our network uses a proxy for monitoring the traffic and our rules stipulate that all the communication must go via the organizations proxy. The documentation on PM2 website states that PM2 does not have any proxy support till now, I can add the proxy config in the NodeJs environment and make the application run and pass by the proxy by using "node *.js" however I cant deploy the application like that, does anyone know of any other tools besides PM2 or some settings with pm2 that can help me?

Comment: Are you referring to connecting PM2 to keymetrics.io for remote monitoring? Because when just locally used as process manager, PM2 doesn't do any outgoing connection as far as I'm aware (unless you mean `pm2 install` which just calls `npm install` under the hood, which should already respect proxy environment variables).

Comment: And I didn't test it but I'd assume that the proxy environment variables would work there also, did you try it? `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY`

Comment: @CherryDT Yes I did try setting  `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` in the linux environment file but no luck, as to your first question no our network has its own proxy config and monitoring and they want to monitor any traffic going out or coming in, in our  application the port 80 and 443 were opened but they still need to be monitored.

Comment: But that doesn't make sense. The listening party cannot control whether _incoming_ connections come through a proxy or not.

Comment: It's much like saying all letters now need to be inspected before they are delivered. You as recipient can't control who delivers the mail to your mailbox...

Comment: Your company's network firewall would have to be configured to route the connections through the corporate proxy instead before they are forwarded to your application's port 80.

Comment: Where does it say that PM2 doesn't support proxy'?